# How to block a certain element on the page with AdBlock by its text-content?

Tags: adblock

I am trying to hide all the spans on YouTube, which contain the string 'view' in them by following [these instructions](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters).

However, it does not work, and I keep getting *Invalid CSS selector syntax* errors.

This is the HTML structure:

[image]

These are the rules that the selector should adhere to:

1. Should hide the span.
2. Work for YouTube website.
3. Have parent **div** with **id="metadata-line"**.
4. Have **view** string inside their text-content.

**This and some other attempts do not work:**
www.youtube.com##DIV:-abp-has(span:-abp-contains(view))

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
www.youtube.com#?#DIV#metadata-line span:-abp-contains(view)
```

You were almost there. Just missed the `#?#` part. :-)

Comment: Thanks! But this covers the entire metadata-line div, not the span itself.

Comment: Are you sure? I inserted the rule in ABP custom filter. Only the span saying `xxx views` got hidden from page. https://screenshots.firefox.com/BellsXxdIU5Zb44M/www.youtube.com